# iOS 9.3.2 exception: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) crash report from apple

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, ios9.3

Apple gave me below crash report. I checked with other questions similar to EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) crashes but that don't helpful to me to solve my crash. Apple specified in comment that these crashes are in iOS 9.3.2 and I checked same with other OS and working fine.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Here is crash report with all required information and logs for Thread 1, I think this will necessary

```
Incident Identifier: D5E9014C-59EE-44EA-8E7E-45D74466EE2F
CrashReporter Key:   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             My App [248]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F19FB288-F626-4887-AFFE-34B5A465BFAD/My App.app/My App
Identifier:          com.myapp
Version:             1.2 (1.2.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-05-18 16:52:31.31 -0700
Launch Time:         2016-05-18 16:52:30.30 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.2 (13F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000183338f9c
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183338f9c 0x183334000 + 20380
1   My App                      0x00000001002ccf90 0x100040000 + 2674576
2   My App                      0x00000001002ccf90 0x100040000 + 2674576
3   UIKit                           0x00000001885bcc40 0x1885a8000 + 85056
4   UIKit                           0x00000001885bc844 0x1885a8000 + 84036
5   My App                      0x00000001000e6644 0x100040000 + 681540
6   My App                      0x00000001000e50b0 0x100040000 + 676016
7   My App                      0x00000001001f07b0 0x100040000 + 1771440
8   My App                      0x00000001002fe314 0x100040000 + 2876180
9   UIKit                           0x00000001885bcc40 0x1885a8000 + 85056
10  UIKit                           0x000000018867d230 0x1885a8000 + 873008
11  UIKit                           0x000000018867d108 0x1885a8000 + 872712
12  UIKit                           0x000000018867c350 0x1885a8000 + 869200
13  UIKit                           0x000000018867bef4 0x1885a8000 + 868084
14  UIKit                           0x000000018867bb1c 0x1885a8000 + 867100
15  UIKit                           0x000000018867ba84 0x1885a8000 + 866948
16  UIKit                           0x00000001885b81e4 0x1885a8000 + 66020
17  QuartzCore                      0x0000000185f4a994 0x185f3c000 + 59796
18  QuartzCore                      0x0000000185f455d0 0x185f3c000 + 38352
19  QuartzCore                      0x0000000185f45490 0x185f3c000 + 38032
20  QuartzCore                      0x0000000185f44ac0 0x185f3c000 + 35520
21  QuartzCore                      0x0000000185f44820 0x185f3c000 + 34848
22  QuartzCore                      0x0000000185f3dde4 0x185f3c000 + 7652
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183414728 0x183334000 + 919336
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001834124cc 0x183334000 + 910540
25  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018333cc70 0x183334000 + 35952
26  UIKit                           0x000000018862b94c 0x1885a8000 + 538956
27  UIKit                           0x0000000188626088 0x1885a8000 + 516232
28  My App                      0x0000000100342414 0x100040000 + 3154964
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182eda8b8 0x182ed8000 + 10424

Activity ID:             0x00000000000050d0
Activity Name:           starting resolver activity
Activity Image Path:     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
Activity Image UUID:     A8E4200A-ECC7-3E56-A845-8A0E9CB4A6F0
Activity Offset:         0x0003333c
Activity Running Time:   6148914683.455229 sec



Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1456b7cc0.events
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182fdd02c 0x182fdc000 + 4140
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182eba394 0x182ea8000 + 74644
2   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a1aed4c 0x18a1ac000 + 11596
3   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a1b3804 0x18a1ac000 + 30724
4   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a1eec44 0x18a1ac000 + 273476
5   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a1ec898 0x18a1ac000 + 264344
6   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a1ec7cc 0x18a1ac000 + 264140
7   CoreLocation                    0x000000018a1eda18 0x18a1ac000 + 268824
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001830f4f68 0x1830f0000 + 20328
9   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001830f2d10 0x1830f0000 + 11536
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182ea9578 0x182ea8000 + 5496
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182ead864 0x182ea8000 + 22628
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182eb5694 0x182ea8000 + 54932
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182eac978 0x182ea8000 + 18808
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182eb5694 0x182ea8000 + 54932
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182eacf80 0x182ea8000 + 20352
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182eb5694 0x182ea8000 + 54932
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182eacf80 0x182ea8000 + 20352
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182ea947c 0x182ea8000 + 5244
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182eb7914 0x182ea8000 + 63764
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182eb70b0 0x182ea8000 + 61616
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001830c1470 0x1830c0000 + 5232
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001830c1020 0x1830c0000 + 4128
```

Comment: That crash report needs symbolicating.

Comment: And any code would be appreciated

Comment: I am using fabric in my application but it is not displaying any crashes in past 48 hours. In addition, I  really don't have any idea from where it can be crashed. :(.

Comment: @trojanfoe would you please explain in some detail what actually i need to do ?

Comment: Do a search.  There are tons of questions about it on this site.

Comment: @trojanfoe I checked many answers for this error. As per answers I am not manually setting any breakpoint crashes or exception. Other than that I am not able to get crash details from crash reports as they mentioned in different answers. Would you please pass me some referral link to resolve this? It would be highly appreciated.  :)

Comment: I just typed "ios how to symbolicate crash logs" into google and got loads of hits.